# Proving base Units of SI are not enough for numerical computations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, units, rotational-kinematics

I have been working on a way to prove that the base unit of SI is not enough for numerical computations to make sense. What I mean by that is let's say you're given units of angular velocity to be [1/s] and if you want to calculate angular displacement it's not enough(you need a unit of an angle like rad, grads, deg). Now prove that [1/s] is not enough for numerical computations involving angular velocity.
 I am trying to approach the problem by using calculus lets say, 
      ω(t) = dθ / dt
then I separate the differentials and integrate them on the bounds. I don't know what to do after that. If you have any other approach, please suggest to me some.

P.S.: this is not a question from any book.

Comment: It's well known that the unit system is not enough to distinguish all possible unlike quantities. For example work has the same units as torque (both are newton-meters). So what?

Comment: Radians, degrees, and grads are dimensionless.  They merely tell how a circle is divided into segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you need a unit of an angle like rad, grads, deg

The [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (SI) includes the radian (rad) as its angular unit. It is a *derived* unit, not a base unit, and is defined as one meter per meter (m/m). The SI unit of angular velocity is rad/s, which, since it is m/m/s in terms of base units, is sometimes simplified to s$^{-1}$. Other angular units such as degrees and gradians are not SI units.

The [official specification](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf) from the *Bureau International des Poids et Mesures* defines the radian in section 2.3.4, “Derived units”.

Comment: I know that but is there a way to prove it using mathematics or using contradiction

Comment: Prove *what*? There is nothing to prove. This is a *definition*.

Comment: If you *knew* that SI included the radian as a meter per meter, why did you claim that “the base unit of SI is not enough for numerical computations to make sense”? People have been using SI units for angular velocity for a very long time with no problems whatsoever.